# Getting Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given /function.php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, session

I'm not so coding friendly, wasted almost 5 days to find a solution. Recently changed the hosting and then it started to happen. At the same time also got other warnings like

> "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/u1524808/genericpanda.com/wp-content/themes/pillshope/functions.php:278) in /var/www/u1524808/genericpanda.com/wp-login.php on line 400"

and due to this I'm unable to log in to WordPress dashboard. Really facing a hard times. Here is the function where I'm getting the error. Really need help, Thank you in advance!!!

```
function register_my_session() {
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['cart']='';
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_POST);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
```

Comment: `themes/pillshope/functions.php:278` has already sent output so `session_start()` cannot run. Might be a good idea to post the relevant part of that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things

1. output is already sent so no use of session_start() however if you want to add and by pass warning write it like

   @session_start()
2. array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_POST);

$_SESSION can be an array, $_SESSION['cart'] has empty string as you have assign it with empty quotes ('')

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = ''
```

so when you try to push data into $_SESSION['cart'] it gives you warning

You can either write $_SESSION['cart'] = [] and then your code works
or

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_POST);
```

can be

```
array_push($_SESSION, $_POST);
```

but later part can wipe all other SESSON data so I suggest you should go with first alternative replace

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = ''
```

with

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = []
```

and try.

Comment: @Robert if that worked let's mark the answer is accepted to let someone else can learn or do research. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using array_push but your $_SESSION['cart'] is a string because you initialize it as ' ' but instead you should do $_SESSION['cart'] = array()